# Making an automatic id in a certain format in a Django model

Tags: python, django, slug

I'm trying to make a field in a model that is automatically created whenever an instance is in a certain way. Here is the relevant code:

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    # This first field is what I'm focusing on
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ssn = USSocialSecurityNumberField(null=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, db_column="date of birth")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    state = USStateField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, default='NJ')
    zipcode = USZipCodeField(blank=True)
    country = CountryField(default='US', blank=True)
    home_phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, validators=[validate_email])
    background = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=BACKGROUND_CHOICES)
    # This field is relevant
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='south_plainfield')
    workforce = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=WORKFORCE_CHOICES, default='--')
    source = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=SOURCE_CHOICES, default='individual')
    refer_by = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=REFER_BY_CHOICES, default='no refer')
    last_status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LAST_STATUS_CHOICES, default='followup')
    newsletter = models.BooleanField()
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # This field is relevant
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    notes = models.TextField()
```

I want to make the student_id field different by making it created automatically in a certain format:

AASSSYYMMDD

AA is 'AV' when the student is paid, and 'PS' when student hasn't. I'm defaulting it to 'PS' for now so no need to worry about it.

SSS is the first three letters of the location in uppercase

YYMMDD is the last two numbers of the year, month, and day of the date field respectively

I've heard that I'm supposed to use AutoSlugField or SlugField, but every single example I've come across only populates them with the entirety of one field, when I want to populate mine with certain parts of multiple fields put together. Does anyone know how to properly take from different fields and format them properly? Thanks.

Edit: Here is some other code:

forms.py

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # STEP 1 FORM
    # student_id = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Student ID")
    # first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="First Name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    # last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Last Name")
    ssn = USSocialSecurityNumberField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="SSN", help_text="Format: xxx-xx-xxxx")
    # gender = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="Gender", choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    dob = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y'], widget=DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'), label="Date of birth", help_text="Format: mm/dd/yyyy")
    # contact_number = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Contact number")
    # address = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Address")
    # city = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="City")
    # state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, initial="NJ", label="State")
    # zipcode = USZipCodeField(label="Zipcode")
    # country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=countries, label="Country", initial="US")
    home_phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control bfh-phone', 'data-format': '+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd'}), max_length=128, label="Home phone")
    cell_phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control bfh-phone', 'data-format': '+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd'}), max_length=128, label="Cell phone")
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), max_length=254, validators=[validate_email], label="Email")
    # background = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BACKGROUND_CHOICES, label="Background")
    # location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, initial="south_plainfield", label="Location")
    # workforce = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WORKFORCE_CHOICES, initial="--", label="Workforce")
    # source = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SOURCE_CHOICES, initial="individual", label="Source")
    # refer_by = forms.ChoiceField(choices=REFER_BY_CHOICES, initial="no refer", label="Refer by")
    # last_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=LAST_STATUS_CHOICES, initial="followup", label="Last status")
    newsletter = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(), label="Newsletter", required=False)
    # created_by = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Created by")
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), label="Date", help_text="Format: yyyy-mm-dd")
    notes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), required=False, label="notes", help_text="less than 1000 characters")

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'ssn', 'gender', 'dob', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'country', 'home_phone', 'cell_phone', 'email', 'background', 'location', 'workforce', 'source', 'refer_by', 'last_status', 'newsletter', 'created_by', 'date', 'notes')
```

views.py

```
def add_Student(request):
    form = StudentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

            return render(request, 'students/add_student_success.html', {})
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'students/add_student.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

The main question is, would this field be your `primary_key` in your model or not?

If not, then the primary key will be Django's default `id`, which is an `AutoField()`. So now you're left with handling `student_id` manually.

What I'd suggest is to create a `post_save` signal handling method, in which you'll set the `student_id` field, like in my example here:

```
def method_for_student_id(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:  # else it results in an infinite loop
        # business logic here to create the student id string
        student_id = ....

        instance.student_id = student_id
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(method_for_student_id, sender=Student)
```

I hope that helps in your case - let me know if that works!

Comment: How would the student_id field look in the model itself? And where would this go in relation to the model?

Comment: You leave this as is, no need to change something regarding the student_id field in your current model structure.

Comment: Should this code go inside of the model or outside? And in regard to the string, how would I extract the numbers from the date field? This is what I'm thinking of so far: 'PV' + instance.location[:3].upper() + however you put the date in. Also, is it dynamic? Say that I want to change the location. Would that change the student id as well?

Comment: That's going outside the model code. In regards to the string, see that `instance` param? That's your current student instance, so eg calling `instance.date` will give you back the date of that instance. Although it's not "dynamic" as you mean it, you should override the model's `save()` method in order to do that

Comment: I am aware of instance.date. I'm saying that I only want the last two numbers of the year, the two numbers of the month, and the two numbers of the date in the student id. I don't want the entire date with the dashes. And 'post_save' is giving me an error. Also, regarding your last statement, is that something I can just leave alone or do I need to do something with it in views?

Comment: I don't think this solution worked. Is it supposed to go before or after the model?

Comment: After the model. Can you share in a pastebin your current code?